# Show/Hide with Checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I am trying to have a section of an html form to show/hide based on a checkbox.  This is the essence code I have:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(className){
        var $input = $(this);
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
            $(className).show();
        else
            $(className).hide();
        }
</script>

<fieldset><legend>Check Here
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('.myClass')" ></legend>
    <span class="myClass">
        <p>This is the text.</p>
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

When you click on the checkbox, the span gets hidden and will not come back.  I have also used `$(this).is(':checked')`.  It appears that `$(this).prop('checked')` is evaluating to **false** whether it is checked or not.  My best guess is that I am using `$(this)` incorrectly.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try: toggle(this,'.myClass')

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HTML, pass `this` from on click event

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle('.myClass', this)" ></legend>
```

JS

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
    var $input = $(obj);
    if ($input.prop('checked')) $(className).hide();
    else $(className).show();
}
```

OR, without using `prop` you can just do:

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
    if ( obj.checked ) $(className).hide();
    else $(className).show();
}
```

OR, in one-line using [`.toggle( display )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
function toggle(className, obj) {
    $(className).toggle( !obj.checked )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use an event handler that is'nt inline, and then just `toggle()` the element based on the checkbox state :

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javaScript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.myClass').toggle(!this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Check Here<input type="checkbox"></legend>
    <span class="myClass">
        <p>This is the text.</p>
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cEAnM/1/)

This would even work with several fieldset's with the same markup.

Comment: This is probably the 'best' answer in general, but it is a little above my skill level; I try only to use coding that I understand.

Answer (score 7):

try binding event via jQuery, and then you can access to `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox").click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      $(".myClass").show();
    else
      $(".myClass").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="text" id="amount">

$document.ready(function() {
 $("input:checked").on("click",function () {
   $("#amount").toggle()
 })
});
```