# Hiding/showing class content if checkbox is ticked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

Can't seem to get the checkbox section working.

The .hide() works fine, but the else refuses to show it again.

Other versions of the same code mess up other bits of script on the page, and toggle is a no go due to loading time (if a visitor clicks it too early it ends up reversed!)

Essentially, all I'm looking for is to hide the content if the checkbox is ticked, and to show it again if it's unticked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.sponsor_table').hide();
    $('.sponsor_address').hide();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[name="remain_anonymous"]:checked')) {
            $('.sponsor_name').hide();
            $('.sponsor_logo').hide();
            $('.sponsor_website').hide();
        } else {
            $('.sponsor_name').show();
            $('.sponsor_logo').show();
            $('.sponsor_website').show();
        }
     });
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[name="cb_sponsor_attendance"]:checked').val() == "Yes"){
            $('.sponsor_table').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.sponsor_address').hide();
        }
        else if($('input[name="cb_sponsor_attendance"]:checked').val() == "No"){
            $('.sponsor_address').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.sponsor_table').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

The full HTML for the checkbox section is:

```
<div id="remain_anonymous-wrap" class="form-row  anonymous_sponsor">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-remain_anonymous">
        Make this donation anonymous?                       <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="Details will not be shared on the site, or at the event"></span>
                </label>
            <span data-required="no" data-type="checkbox"></span>

    <span class="ffm-fields">

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remain_anonymous[]"
                           value="Yes, please don&#039;t share my identity" />
                    Yes, please don't share my identity                 </label>
                            </span>


    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_name-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_name">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_name">
        Your Name/Business Name                     <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="This will be shared both online and on the table at the gala."></span>
                </label>
            <input class="textfield"
           id="ffm-cb_sponsor_name" type="text"
           data-required="no"
           data-type="text" name="cb_sponsor_name"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size=" 100"  />

    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_logo-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_logo">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo">
        Photo/Logo                  </label>

    <div id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-upload-container">
        <div class="ffm-attachment-upload-filelist">
            <a id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-pickfiles" class="button file-selector"
               href="#">Select File(s)</a>

            <span class="ffm-file-validation" data-required="no" data-type="file"></span>
            <ul class="ffm-attachment-list give-thumbnails">
                                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            new Give_FFM_Uploader('ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-pickfiles', 'ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-upload-container', 1, 'cb_sponsor_logo', 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,', 2048 );
        });
    </script>
    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_website-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_website">      <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_website">
        Website                 </label>

    <input id="ffm-cb_sponsor_website" type="url" class="give-url"
           data-required="no" data-type="text"             name="cb_sponsor_website"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size="100"/>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us the `HTML` also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/Hide with Checkbox using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766875/show-hide-with-checkbox-using-jquery)

Comment: @urbz - There is another checkbox on the page, but placed there by a plugin, not by me. I've no idea what code they're using for that, and all the HTML is generated by the plugin. I've tried the suggestions on half dozen other posts here, already... I don't feel I should be marked down for duplication if I've already tried everything I can think of/find? :/

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have class named `sponsor_name` or `sponsor_logo`

Comment: @MilanChheda - Whoops! That one was my fault. I pasted the HTML from the wrong post. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and check:

```js
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      $('.sponsor_name,.sponsor_website,.sponsor_logo').show();
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.sponsor_name,.sponsor_website,.sponsor_logo').hide();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="remain_anonymous-wrap" class="form-row  anonymous_sponsor">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-remain_anonymous">
        Make this donation anonymous?                       <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="Details will not be shared on the site, or at the event"></span>
                </label>
            <span data-required="no" data-type="checkbox"></span>

    <span class="ffm-fields">

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remain_anonymous[]"
                           value="Yes, please don&#039;t share my identity" />
                    Yes, please don't share my identity                 </label>
                            </span>


    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_name-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_name">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_name">
        Your Name/Business Name                     <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="This will be shared both online and on the table at the gala."></span>
                </label>
            <input class="textfield"
           id="ffm-cb_sponsor_name" type="text"
           data-required="no"
           data-type="text" name="cb_sponsor_name"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size=" 100"  />

    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_logo-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_logo">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo">
        Photo/Logo                  </label>

    <div id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-upload-container">
        <div class="ffm-attachment-upload-filelist">
            <a id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-pickfiles" class="button file-selector"
               href="#">Select File(s)</a>

            <span class="ffm-file-validation" data-required="no" data-type="file"></span>
            <ul class="ffm-attachment-list give-thumbnails">
                                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->

    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_website-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_website">      <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_website">
        Website                 </label>

    <input id="ffm-cb_sponsor_website" type="url" class="give-url"
           data-required="no" data-type="text"             name="cb_sponsor_website"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size="100"/>

    </div>
```

Comment: Nope :( Doesn't do anything at all now. Clicking it has no effect.

Comment: Updated. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Alas, the script is already included in the page and working for other elements. All HTML is being generated by a WordPress plugin. I have no control over HTML output, and can't paste the entire thing because it's too long... Web address for example is: [link] (https://project365.site/support/sydney-2017-table-2/)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function in your checkbox

```
  $("input[name=anonymous_sponsor]").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
         $('.sponsor_name').hide();
        $('.sponsor_logo').hide();
        $('.sponsor_website').hide();
    } else {
        $('.sponsor_name').show();
        $('.sponsor_logo').show();
        $('.sponsor_website').show();
    }

    });
```

Comment: Tried a version of this earlier. Doesn't do anything at all :(

Comment: Alas, still doesn't do anything... checking or unchecking the box has no effect.

Comment: where is your check box with  **anonymous_sponsor** name in your code

Comment: Right at the top of the HTML. But even substituting it with 'name=remain_anonymous", which seems to be what the plugin has named it, doesn't work.

Comment: which plugin you use?

Comment: Give WP - charitable donation form plug. This is all generated from their Form Field Manager extension, all barring the bit of script that I posted which I'm trying to use to show/hide select fields based on user input.

Comment: Bah! input name had to include the square brackets! What?! Changing it to remain_anonymous[] seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a input field with a name 'your_input_field_name' `<input name="your_input_field_name" type="checkbox" >` that you want to listen for change

```
$('input[name="your_input_field_name"]').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    //if ture
  }else{
    //if false
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope :( '      $('input[name="remain_anonymous"]').change(function(){
         if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $('.sponsor_name').hide();
                 $('.sponsor_logo').hide();
                 $('.sponsor_website').hide();
         }else{
           $('.sponsor_name').show();
                 $('.sponsor_logo').show();
                 $('.sponsor_website').show();
        }
      });' does nothing at all.

Comment: Bah! input name had to include the square brackets! What?! Changing it to remain_anonymous[] seems to have done the trick!

Comment: You have used an input array. Is there many instances of remain_anonymous? if not get rid of the brackets at the end of the name

Comment: Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wambh6nt/) with a working solution

Comment: I don't know what to say. I copied and pasted your exact code and it just won't work on the page. The minute I remove those square brackets checking the box does absolutely nothing... I can't see anything in my script that would be causing this, so I can only imagine that the problem is with Give's plugin script and some kind of conflict with their built-in checkbox behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Apparently the input name had to match the HTML exactly for this to work properly, including those square brackets that weren't listed in the back end of WordPress (screenshot below).

[image: a back_end]

Changing the input name to: remain_anonymous[] seems to have done the trick. Despite there only being one instance of remain_anonymous on the page, it won't work without them.

I have no clue why, but it's working.

Thank you all for your help, and thank you to ionut for suggesting I post the HTML. First time I've actually looked at it... *doh*

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, I have modified your code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.sponsor_table').hide();
    $('.sponsor_address').hide();
    $('input[name="remain_anonymous[]"]').click(function(evt){
        if($(evt.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
            $('.sponsor_name').hide();
            $('.sponsor_logo').hide();
            $('.sponsor_website').hide();
        } else {
            $('.sponsor_name').show();
            $('.sponsor_logo').show();
            $('.sponsor_website').show();
        }
     });
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[name="cb_sponsor_attendance"]:checked').val() == "Yes"){
            $('.sponsor_table').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.sponsor_address').hide();
        }
        else if($('input[name="cb_sponsor_attendance"]:checked').val() == "No"){
            $('.sponsor_address').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.sponsor_table').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="remain_anonymous-wrap" class="form-row  anonymous_sponsor">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-remain_anonymous">
        Make this donation anonymous?                       <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="Details will not be shared on the site, or at the event"></span>
                </label>
            <span data-required="no" data-type="checkbox"></span>

    <span class="ffm-fields">

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remain_anonymous[]"
                           value="Yes, please don&#039;t share my identity" />
                    Yes, please don't share my identity                 </label>
                            </span>


    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_name-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_name">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_name">
        Your Name/Business Name                     <span class="give-tooltip give-icon give-icon-question"
              data-tooltip="This will be shared both online and on the table at the gala."></span>
                </label>
            <input class="textfield"
           id="ffm-cb_sponsor_name" type="text"
           data-required="no"
           data-type="text" name="cb_sponsor_name"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size=" 100"  />

    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_logo-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_logo">        <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo">
        Photo/Logo                  </label>

    <div id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-upload-container">
        <div class="ffm-attachment-upload-filelist">
            <a id="ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-pickfiles" class="button file-selector"
               href="#">Select File(s)</a>

            <span class="ffm-file-validation" data-required="no" data-type="file"></span>
            <ul class="ffm-attachment-list give-thumbnails">
                                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            //new Give_FFM_Uploader('ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-pickfiles', 'ffm-cb_sponsor_logo-upload-container', 1, 'cb_sponsor_logo', 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,', 2048 );
        });
    </script>
    </div><div id="cb_sponsor_website-wrap" class="form-row  sponsor_website">      <label class="give-label" for="ffm-cb_sponsor_website">
        Website                 </label>

    <input id="ffm-cb_sponsor_website" type="url" class="give-url"
           data-required="no" data-type="text"             name="cb_sponsor_website"
           placeholder="" value=""
           size="100"/>

    </div>
```

Comment: Works, but affects ALL checkboxes on the page. Every time any of them is clicked you get the show/hide behaviour. So if you've ticked "remain_anonymous" and then decide you want to cover the transaction fee or accept terms and conditions you get the hidden fields show up again.

Comment: I have changed jquery selector to name="remain_anonymous[]" which you are using in the html. hope that helps. pls see answer edit